# Draw vertical line in a Rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

I am developing a MVC application and I have a cshtml page where I have a html table and I need to be able to draw a vertical line (positioned anywhere in a td column)  that row spans the entire section of the table and sub table.  The vertical line can be positioned anywhere in the td section.  Not sure if this matters but I am using Bootstrap.  I have taken out the bootstrap class reference but I still have the problem.  Please help!

Here is my code:

```
Here is my code:
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <tr style="vertical-align:central">              
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:130px">&nbsp; </td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;width:100px">&nbsp; </td>
        <td>Jan 2014 </td>
        <td>Feb 2014 </td>
        <td >Mar 2014</td>
        <td>Apr 2014 </td>
        <td>May 2014 </td>
        <td>Jun 2014 </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap">&nbsp </td>
    <td colspan="6"  
        <table  style="width:100%" >
        <tr>            
            <td style="background-color:lightgray;height:10px;width:5.52%" title="01 Jan 2014 - 10 Jan 2014"></td>
            <td style="background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow;height:10px;width:14.36%" title="11 Jan 2014 - 05 Feb 2014"></td>
            <td style="background-color:lightgreen;height:10px;width:80.11%" title="06 Feb 2014 - 30 Jun 2014"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
    <td colspan="1">&nbsp; </td>
    <td  colspan="181">
        <table  style="width:100%" >        
        <tr>            
            <td style="background-color:lightgray;height:10px;width:28.73%" title="01 Jan 2014 - 21 Feb 2014"></td>
            <td  style="background-color:lightblue;height:10px;width:33.15%" title="22 Feb 2014 - 23 Apr 2014"></td>
            <td  style="background-color:lightsalmon;height:10px;width:3.87%" title="23 Apr 2014 - 30 Apr 2014"></td>
            <td  style="background-color:yellowgreen;height:10px;width:33.15%" title="01 May 2014 - 30 Jun 2014"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="1 </td>
    <td colspan="1"> </td>
    <td  colspan="181">
        <table  style="width:100%" >        
        <tr>            
            <td style="background-color:indianred;height:10px;width:100%" title="01 Jan 2014 - 30 Jun 2014"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For one thing, if you look at the syntax highlighting, you can see you didn't close one of your tags (near the bottom: `<td colspan="1 </td>` should be `<td colspan="1"> </td>`).

Comment: Is it `rowspan` or `colspan` problem? And why do you have colspan="181"? I don't see 181 columns but 8 columns in your first row for example.